# Store another page H1 content in var and check if there's a word

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have my index page and another page called 'p1.html'. I need to store the H1 content from the p1.html, onto a var on my index page, to then check later, if the h1 in var contains a specific word

Something like:

```
var h1Content = $.get('p1.html', function(html){
    $.text($('h1',html).text());
  });
// some other code blablabla
// some other code blablabla
// some other code blablabla
if (h1Content.indexOf("Stock") != -1) {
    console.log("H1 has Stock");
} else if (h1Content.indexOf("Turismo") != -1) {
            console.log("H1 has Turismo");
}
```

The p1.html H1 here:

```
   <h1 id="Title">Camp. Bras. Stock Car - 2ª Bateria</h1>
```

What Am I doing wrong?

The idea is that I can use the above concept, within this code:

```
var TimerLoad, TimerChange;
    var MaxNum, Rafraichir, Changement, ClassementReduit, ClassementReduitXpremier;
    var UrlRefresh, UrlChange;
    Rafraichir = 3000;
    Changement = 15000;
    MaxNum = 1;
    ClassementReduit = 0;
    ClassementReduitXpremier = 10;
    // VAR WITH H1 from p1 stored goes here <<<<<

    function Load(url, target) {
        var xhr;
        var fct;
        if (UrlChange) url = UrlRefresh;
        else UrlRefresh = url;
        UrlChange = 0;
        if (TimerLoad) clearTimeout(TimerLoad);
        try {
            xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
            } catch (e2) {
                try {
                    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest
                } catch (e3) {
                    xhr = false
                }
            }
        }
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
                if (ClassementReduit == 0) document.getElementById(target).innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                else document.getElementById(target).innerHTML = ExtraireClassementReduit(xhr.responseText)
                //console.log("18");
                // IF/ELSE CONDITIONS TO CHECK IF H1 have a specific word GOES HERE <<<
        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be doing:

```
var h1Content;
$.get('p1.html', function(html){
   h1Content = $('h1',html).text();
});

function checkH1() {
  if (h1Content) {    
   if (h1Content.indexOf("Stock") != -1) {
     console.log("H1 has Stock");
   } else if (h1Content.indexOf("Turismo") != -1) {
     console.log("H1 has Turismo");
   }
  } else {
    setTimeout(checkH1, 1000); //In case h1Content is empty because the ajax call didn't retrieve anything yet, it waits 1 second and fires this function again.
  }
}
checkH1(); //You can call this from wherever you want, may be attaching it as an event.
```

Don't forget that `$.get()` is an asynchronous call so, the process won't block until it gets a response, it will continue working and run the lines below your `$.get()` call and the variable h1Content will be `undefined`.

Comment: The idea is that I need to store the H1 at the beginning of the code, to fire a condition later, after some other codes. The 'if' condition should go oustide the '.get'. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but you should be sure that the h1Content is loaded before accessing the condition. Let me edit my answer

Comment: Thanks man. Sorry for the lame questions, I'm on early stages of jquery coding. How do I make this to run as the page is loaded for the user, withou the trigger "checkH1();"?

Comment: Hmm i am not sure if i am understanding. What is exactly what you want to do?

Comment: Updated my question with the code I'm running, and where I need to trigger the codes you helped me with.

Comment: In that case, you could write the $.get code below your variables declaratiions, write the function just below it and then, inside the "Load" function, where you added the comment, add the call to the funciton checkH1(); That should work.

Comment: Couldn't get exactly like that, but I wrap up some of the code with the $.get and that was a success. Thanks a lot for all the help :D